# How do I build a responsive navigation menu within a grid container?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple navigation

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

that I want to be responsive where the links resize (horizontally) based on user device.  This nav rests comfortably within a sub-grid container of a grid-container (    .class {display: subgrid;} not used as its buggy).

CSS for the grid-container is as follows:

```
.container {
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header header header"
  "nav nav nav nav"
  "main main main main"
  "footer footer footer footer"
}
```

CSS for the subgrid (nav) container is as follows:

```
.ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "home about contact";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 25%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The`grid-template-areas` are declared accordingly:

```
.home {grid-area: home;}
.about {grid-area: about};
.contact {grid-area: contact};
```

I have tinkered with this, particularly the `grid-template-areas`, for sometime now without progress. I am not sure if I should scrap the `subgrid container` altogether or if there is a simple step that I am overlooking.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: In your `.container`, you could just write "header" "nav" "main" "footer", since each of the rows are identical....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS Grid for the overall layout makes sense.

Using CSS Grid for a simple navigation menu, although it's workable, may be overkill. There's a simpler way to achieve the goal: Flexbox.

Make your `nav` grid item also a flex container:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px; /* non-essential; for demo only */
}

/* non-essential; for demo only */
a {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I modified my code per your advice, but without a positive result.  I thought my pc was acting buggy so I stripped the entire project of nothing but the navigation and it was indeed responsive.  Thus, I confirm the functionality of the applied javascript, which leaves me wondering if I should place the <nav> (display: flex;) outside of the main-container (display: grid).

Comment: Did just that (put the <nav> outside of the main container) and it was responsive to the extent that once I clicked the hamburger icon the <a> links displayed horizontally and did not apply css styles once clicked.  To that end, I will go back and look at how flexbox works with grid.  Thank s again for your help.  I will return to this thread once I find a solution.

Comment: have a look at Kevin Powell's YouTube videos about navbar. they might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

For example, you the following html navbar:

```
<nav class="nav-menu">
   <a>Item 1</a>
   <a>Item 2</a>
   <a>Item 3</a>
</nav>
```

You could use a rule to set a different width

```
.nav-menu {
   display: flex;

   a {
      width: 25px;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .nav-menu a {
      width: 20px;
   }
}
```

The new width inside `@media` will replace what was assigned before if the screen size is bigger than 500px.